# Default/Parameterised Constructor = How to edit it in methods for all JFrames in Package

Tags: java, netbeans

For my PAT for school, I made my default constructor and parameterised constructor as seen here:

```
public class Client
{

//attributes
private String clientName;
private String clientPass;
private double currentBal;
private double savingsBal;
private boolean verify;

//default constructor

public Client()
{
            clientName = "";
            clientPass = "";
            currentBal = 0.0;
            savingsBal = 0.0;
            verify = false; 
}
//parameterised constructor
private Client(String username,String password,int accNum,
            double curBal,double savBal, boolean ver)
{
            clientName = username;
            clientPass = password;
            currentBal = curBal;
            savingsBal = savBal;
            verify = ver;
}
```

The problem is, I have created a few methods after this, and for them to work properly, they need to change the values that are initially assigned in my constructors for all the different forms in my package. 
Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. No matter what I do, the variables are only temporarily changed.
Am I missing something? Is there something I should have done differently in my constructors, or do I need to do something extra in my methods for this to change.

All help greatly appreciated. :)

EDIT: 
Here is one of my methods:

```
public void newClient(String username,String password) throws IOException
    {
        //Sets username and password to user input and assigns the Client 
account balances.
        clientName = username;
        clientPass = password;
        savingsBal = (int)((Math.random()*100000000)) / 100.0;
        currentBal = (int)((Math.random()*100000000)) / 100.0;
        //Calls BufferedWriter to write a line to the text file with all 
user information.
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (new 
FileWriter("ClientDatabase.txt",true));

bw.write(clientName+"_"+clientPass+"_"+currentBal+"_"+savingsBal);
            bw.newLine();
            //Closes BufferedWriter
            bw.close();
                }
    //Verifies new Client via their username and password.
```

That works fine, and it is all written to the text file. But when I try to use any of those values in any of my other JFrames, and it seems as though they have been reset to 0 or null...

Comment: You do not reference an instance of `Client` class in your example. What class is `newClient`-Method a member of? Probably not `Client`. You can only use class variables like this inside that very class. Outside you need a reference (like `Client c = new Client()` ) and then you can mutate that instances members (like `c.setName(aName)` )

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you haven't actually used the values obtained in the newClient method (username and password) to initialize a new Client object with your paramaterized constructer; you simply assigned them to some global values. Make sure you create a new instance of Client, and have the rest of your JFrames reference that object.

Comment: Hi @Jochem Kleine, how would I go about doing that?
As I'm sure you can tell, I'm fairly new to this. :)

Comment: I'm assuming newClient is in a different class than Client itself, is that true? (if not, it should probably be) What you want newClient to do is make a new Client object; an instance of the Client class. This is where your paramaterized constructor comes into play. Instead of 'Client c = new Client ();', you can create a client object like so: 'Client c = new Client (username, password, accNum, curball, savBall, ver)'.


If you havn't already done so, create getters and setters (methods like 'public String getName()') for retrieving the client name from your client object, as shown by @Fildor

Comment: I tried to be elaborate, ask away if anything is unclear.